# How do I get these animated obstacles to work right with fluid physics and prevent freak outs like this?

Tags: physics, keyframes, fluid-simulation, baking

I recently tried to bake a fluid physics simulation with a mixing vat style setup. I did some basic parenting and keyframes to animate the stirrer, but the fluid immediately freaked out completely (or as immediately as it could have been, considering it baked for 3 days).

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Mli_sOjYDc

What settings do I need to change to keep this from happening? I've heard about something called exporting an animated mesh, but I can't seem to find anything on the internet about it.

Answer (score 2):

Select your obstacle object, go to physics in the properties pane, under fluid obstacle settings there's a checkbox called Export Animated Mesh. Use it :-)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you can do.

1. The mixing blade has to much of an impact. Among the obstacle settings, change impact from 1.0 to something like 0.5 or lower. The default setting of 1.0 is almost always too high.
2. Check the geometry of the vat. Does it get its thickness from the solidify modifier? If so, apply the modifier before baking, or maybe just move it to the top of the modifier stack, before the fluid sim.
3. In the domain settings, uncheck "remove air bubbles". This may leave a small space between the fluid and the surrounding obstacle, but unless the obstacle is transparent, it probably won't matter.

Answer (score -2):

You might be able to save yourself a few headaches by using a domain the same shape as your container, rather than a generic cube.

Try selecting the inside edges of your container, Shift-D to copy, and build a new domain from that. Be sure to reverse the normals after you do this, and put a top and bottom face on this new mesh/domain.

Once that's done you can enlarge the domain bigger than the inside edge of the container, and shape the top for splash.

Controlling the splash... that requires lots of tweaks, as scale can be a factor for the simulation, as can elements that affect viscosity and mass.

Comment: I don't think using any other form except for cube as fluid domain can save some time because [it will be treated as cube when computing](https://www.blender.org/manual/fr/physics/fluid/types/domain.html); same applies for other types of physics sim. It would be possible splitting animation in parts and baking several smaller domains though; as always, efficiency depends on situation.

Comment: @OroborosNZ as per the manual: **The shape of the object does not matter because it will always be treated like a box** (The lengths of the bounding box sides can be different). So, usually there won’t be any reason to use another shape than a box. If you need obstacles or other boundaries than a box to interfere with the fluid flow, you need to insert additional obstacle objects inside the domain boundary.